# How to use a combination of column values to filter data and create subsets?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm new to python and would like some help in scaling a project I'm working on.

I have a data set with 25 columns. I need to filter that data by the unique combinations of 3 particular columns. Then name each of the unique filters as a subset (preferably just the combo of the values in each of the 3 columns).

So, I have the code to find the unique combinations of just the three columns that I need. I thought that would be a good start.

```
unique = m_nlsn[['Market Break','Demographic', 'Playback Period']].drop_duplicates(subset=['Market Break','Demographic', 'Playback Period'])
```

Now, I need to know how do I use these unique combinations to filter and name subsets? For instance, if I have 10 unique combinations, I want 10 different subsets based on the values in those 3 particular columns. See below I was filtering the unique combinations MANUALLY.

```
comp_hh_live = m_nlsn.loc[(m_nlsn['Market Break'] == "Composite") 
                 & (m_nlsn['Demographic'] == "Household")
                 & (m_nlsn['Playback Period'] == "Live | TV with Digital | Linear with VOD")]
```

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] ?

Comment: Could you create a new column that combines the three, then do a groupby() on that column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use a dictionary for a variable number of variables**

In this instance, you can use `dict` with `groupby`. The benefit here is you do not need to explicitly calculate the unique combinations, as this is taken care of by the `GroupBy` object.

```
d = dict(tuple(m_nlsn.groupby(['Market Break', 'Demographic', 'Playback Period'])))
```

You can then access individual groups via tuple keys. It's also straightforward to assign them to variables; for instance:

```
comp_hh_live = d[('Composite', 'Household', 'Live | TV with Digital | Linear with VOD')]
```

If you find this too verbose, I recommend you use [Categorical Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html) to set and rename categories. Using this method will also provide other benefits from lower memory usage.

Comment: Thanks so much for the feedback. So, the dict can replace the subset I created with my code (I named it unique), but in your second code snippet, the subsets are being made by manually typing in the value combinations. I'm hoping to get this manual part automated.

Comment: @SoSincere3, In a way, you don't *need* to assign each cut to a separate variable. Just use `d[('Composite', 'Household', 'Live | TV with Digital | Linear with VOD')]`. This is very efficient O(1) access. If these strings are two long, you might want to create your own dictionary mapping values, e.g. `{'Live': 'Live | TV with Digital | Linear with VOD'}`, etc.

Comment: Essentially, creating lots of variables manually is not recommended. You  should use a dictionary to store and access a variable number of related variables.

Comment: I see. The issue is that I will then need to merge each of these groups to another data set and run regression on each of them. I'll need to be able to call them without necessarily knowing what the combination values are because the data that I receive can have different values each time.

Comment: @SoSincere3, Then you need to assign variables as above. Not sure how you would try to get `comp_hh_live` from `('Composite', 'Household', 'Live | TV with Digital | Linear with VOD')`. There's no logic that will automate this transformation.

Comment: Gotcha. I'm thinking I could create a column that combines the unique value columns (like @rcriii suggested) and name the subset based on the value of the combined columns. Example: Composite Household Live | TV with Digital | Linear with VOD. It would be longer than my shorthand name, but still identifiable.

Comment: @SoSincere3, You can do that. In my opinion, `|` (or any) delimiter adds no value. Better to use a `tuple` than a long string.